# WebFinger library for PHP?

Tags: php, webfinger

My goal is to retrieve the [OpenID](http://openid.net/) [identity provider](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#terminology) for a given e-mail address, and so I'm looking for a [WebFinger](http://hueniverse.com/webfinger/) library written in PHP. Unfortunately I fail to find a suitable one.

The lib should be [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/)-installable and be usable standalone, or at least with only a few dependencies.

Any recommendations?

---

What I've found so far:

- [PSX Framework](http://phpsx.org/) is a quite big framework that offers only one PEAR compatible package that contains everything. Webfinger, Yadis, Logging, Session etc - too much. Also no docblocks.
- [find by email's webfinger.php](https://github.com/petewarden/findbyemail/blob/master/webfinger.php) is only a file with a bunch of functions that don't support OpenID discovery. No unit tests, not usable standalone.
- http://status.net/ has a Discovery class in `lib/discovery.php` that supports Webfinger. Not PEAR-installable, not standalone.
- https://github.com/walkah/discovery-php - standalone library. Not PEAR-installable, doesn't support the full spec (e.g. no HTTPS-first fetching)
- SocialIgniter's WebFinger implementation: https://github.com/socialigniter/socialigniter/blob/master/application/libraries/Webfinger.php - does not fetch HTTPS resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've began implementing it myself since there doesn't seem to be a good existing libary

The [XML_XRD PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_XRD) is an implementation of XRD, which gets me 80% to WebFinger support. See [the code](https://github.com/pear/XML_XRD).

I also wrote the [Net_WebFinger package](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_WebFinger).